# Cropping Images .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to do a simple crop of an image, but for some reason it is not respecting my starting x,y location.  It is always starting the crop at 0,0.  The following is what I am doing:

```
Bitmap original = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

        int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtX.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(txtY.Text);
        int dX = Convert.ToInt32(txtDeltaX.Text);
        int dY = Convert.ToInt32(txtDeltaY.Text);

        Point loc = new Point(x, y);
        Size cropSize = new Size(dX, dY);

        Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(loc, cropSize);

        Bitmap bmpCrop = CropImage(original, cropArea);

        pictureBox1.Image = bmpCrop;
```

The cropping method:

```
public Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap source, Rectangle section)
    {
        // An empty bitmap which will hold the cropped image  
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        // Draw the given area (section) of the source image  
        // at location 0,0 on the empty bitmap (bmp)  
        g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        return bmp;
    }
```

This should be very simple, but for some reason its not working.  Its cropping it, just at 0,0.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that `section` is the proper dimensions?

Comment: You might want to include what the text of your textboxes are.

Comment: I have verified that the section is correct, and that it has values for x and y other then 0,0...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to use

```
g.DrawImage(source, section);
```

Anyway this function works:

```
public Bitmap CropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, 
                         int cropX, int cropY, 
                         int cropWidth, int cropHeight)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
    Bitmap cropped = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    return cropped;
}
```

Comment: @noobS41bot: if you use `pictureBox1.Image = CropBitmap(pictureBox1.Image, x, y, dX, dY)` still doesn't work?

Comment: MY BAD! The cropping was working, however I had additional code after that was turning to greyscale, and forgot to change which image I was re-paintnig.  Was using the original, instead of the new cropped image, so it looked like it was not moving. SORRY GUYS! Guess I should have posted all of it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimageunscaledandclipped.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use, something like this :

```
g.DrawImage(source, x, y, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: Right.  That is where we want to start drawing the cropped image on the new bitmap, the section Rectangle should be telling it where to get the cropped image.